# Elementary submodels in stationary logic.

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

In the paper ["Stationary Logic" by Barwise, Kaufmann and Makkai](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484378900037) the authors prove that stationary Logic L(aa) has Löwenheim number $\aleph_1$, i.e. every satisfiable set of sentences has a model of size at most $\aleph_1$. (only countable signatures are considered)

It is then asked whether in fact the stronger result holds, that every structure has an elementary substructure of size at most $\aleph_1$.

In a footnote on p.222 it is mentioned that this question depends on set theory:
"If V = L, then there is a structure of size $\omega_2$ with no L(aa)-elementary submodel of power $\omega_1$"

I'm looking for a reference where this argument is worked out in more detail or if it is not too long maybe someone here can give me a more detailed argument.

Edit: L(aa) arises from first order logic in the following way:
We add new variables $X_1,X_2,\dots$ for unary countable relations, which lead to new atomic formulas $Xt$ for a first order term t. Now the formation rules for formulas are that of first order logic together with the new quantifier (aa) which binds one relation variable, i.e if $\varphi$ is a formula, so is $(aa)X_i\varphi$ the meaning of which is defined by
$$\mathfrak{A}\models(aa)X_i\varphi \Leftrightarrow \{R\in P_{\omega_1}(A)|\mathfrak{A}\models \varphi[R]\}\in D(A)$$
where $D(A)$ is the club filter on $P_{\omega_1}(A)$. So aa says for almost all relations.

Comment: Can you write the definition of $L(aa)$ here?

Comment: Yes, i have editet a description in. @AsafKaragila

Comment: I think $(L_{\omega_2}, \in)$ itself should be a counterexample assuming $V=L$. By condensation, any elementary substructure is again a level of $L$, so we would have to have $L_{\alpha}\prec_{aa} L_{\omega_2}$ for some $\alpha<\omega_2$. This seems like it should be impossible, although I'm blanking on exactly why . . .

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with the fact that $\square_{\omega_{1}}$ holds in $L$, so stationary reflection fails at $\omega_{2}$. It doesn't seem like you need to know how to define a non-reflecting stationary set to complete the argument, since each subset of $\omega_{2}$ exists in $L_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha < \omega_{3}$, but you may need to use the fact that Chang's Conjecture fails to see that any submodel of cardinality $\aleph_{1}$ has to contain $\omega_{1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assertion that ``the L-S number of stationary logic is $\omega_2$" is equivalent to a principle I introduced a while back, called "Diagonal Reflection Principle for internally club sets" ($\text{DRP}_{\text{IC}}$).  The equivalence is proved in the following recent preprint, available on Fuchino's [website](http://fuchino.ddo.jp/preprints.html):

--Sakaé Fuchino, André Ottenbreit Maschio Rodrigues and Hiroshi Sakai, Strong Löwenheim-Skolem theorems for stationary logics, I

This principle is very strong, since it implies failures of many square principles (and is expected to be equiconsistent with a supercompact).  In particular, it fails in L.

Comment: Welcome to the Thunderdome, Sean!